# Как убрать web_war_exploded из url?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tomcat, развертывание, jetbrains

После того, как запускаю приложение на `TomCat v9.0.36`, моя дефолтная страница выглядит так:

```
http://localhost:8081/web_war_exploded/
```

**Вопрос:** как из этого URL сделать такой:

```
http://localhost:8081/
```

web.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">

</web-app>
```

Конфиг TomCat. Удаление из поля URL ни к чему хорошему не привело:

[image: Конфиг TomCat]

Возможно что-то в настройках Deployment, но увы, я не знаю что нужно изменить.

[image: Возможно что-то в настройках Deployment]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На закладке `Deployment` в поле `Application context` указывается, в какой директории разворачивать приложение:

> **Run ⇒ Edit Configurations ⇒ Deployment ⇒ Application context**

[image: Run/Debug Configurations]

Answer (score 0):

В `pom.xml` находим тэг `build` и добавляем в него тэг `finalName`. Должно выглядеть примерно так.

```
<build>
    <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

`${project.name}` будет ссылаться на тэг . Впрочем по `Ctrl+B` в IntelliJ Idea можно перейти к нужной переменной.